# Foreach no envio de emails

Tags: php, html5

Nó código abaixo envio um email para determinado destinatário porém preciso por o número de faturas tudo no mesmo, no código abaixo ele cria um email para cada fatura.

Comentei no código onde eu gostaria que o `foreach` fosse adicionado para funcionar de acordo, porém não consigo fazer funcionar devido a sintaxe.

Resumindo passar o `foreach` que já existe no topo do código para fazer somente nos dados da `table` no `body` do e-mail que será enviado.

```
foreach ($class->ListaFaturas($cnpj) as $dados) {
        $fatura = $dados->getFatura().'<br>';
        $dtemissao = $dados->getDtEmissao().'<br>';
        $dtvencimento = $dados->getDtVencimento().'<br>';
        $valor = $dados->getVlSaldo().'<br>';

        $mail->From = "teste@teste.com.br"; #Seu e-mail
        $mail->FromName = "teste";

        $mail->AddAddress($email,$nome);

        $mail->IsHTML(true); 

        $mail->Subject = "Faturas em atraso";


        #Assunto da mensagem
        $mail->Body = "

        <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Número da Fatura</th>
                <th>Data de Emissão</th>
                <th>Data de Vencimento</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <!-- Foreach aqui -->
               <td>$fatura</td>
               <td>$dtemissao</td>
               <td>$dtvencimento</td>
               <td>$valor</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

        ";

        $mail->AltBody = "";

        $enviado = $mail->Send();

        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
        $mail->ClearAttachments();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa fazer o foreach e montar a mensagem antes do código de envio então.
Algo como:

```
$mensagem=array(); // Vou salvar cada fatura como mensagem nesta array
// Criar cabeçalho da mensagem
$mensagem[]= "<table><thead><tr><th>Número da Fatura</th><th>Data de Emissão</th><th>Data de Vencimento</th><th>Valor</th></tr></thead>";
foreach ($class->ListaFaturas($cnpj) as $dados) {
    $fatura = $dados->getFatura().'<br>';
    $dtemissao = $dados->getDtEmissao().'<br>';
    $dtvencimento = $dados->getDtVencimento().'<br>';
    $valor = $dados->getVlSaldo().'<br>';
    $mensagem[]="<tr><td>$fatura</td><td>$dtemissao</td><td>$dtvencimento</td><td>$valor</td></tr>";
}
// Criar o fim da mensagem:
$mensagem[]= "</tbody></table>";
$mail->From = "teste@teste.com.br"; #Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = "teste";

$mail->AddAddress($email,$nome);

$mail->IsHTML(true); 

$mail->Subject = "Faturas em atraso";
#Assunto da mensagem
// Agora eu junto tudo:
$mail->Body = implode("",$mensagem);
$mail->AltBody = "";
$enviado = $mail->Send();
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();
```